# NeoLoad Login 500 Error: Adf_Faces-30200

Tags: oracle, jsf, load-testing, oracle-adf, neoload

I'm trying to test java web application (jsf) that uses oracle adf-faces. When I record my test, the application is working fine but when I later check the user, then on login.jsf page, just before authentication and home pages, I get 500 Internal server error that says:

> ADF_FACES-30200:For more information, please see the server's error log for an entry beginning with: The UIViewRoot is null. Fatal exception during PhaseId: RESTORE_VIEW 1.

Some more info: My login.jsf page is referred by previous login page that has jsession id appended to it. However, as far as I understand, neoload automatically handles jsessionid (I did try to set a parameter for it though and it didn't fix the error)

Also login.jsf page itself is a referrer to authentication page that in its turn is a referrer to a home page of an application, and the latter are both redirect pages (do not use manual definition) so they are not played during the check because of this error:

> login.jsf page uses POST method and it has the following POST parameters: *pt1:username, pt1:password, org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.faces.FORM, Adf-Window-Id, javax.faces.ViewState, Adf-Page-Id, oracle.adf.view.rich.DELTAS, event, event.pt1:loginCommandButton*

I use set of users (I have a variable for username and password) and I handle `javax.faces.ViewState` manually with a jsf parameter (it used to give me errors).

I would appreciate any help greatly!